# How to find a point on the intersection line between two triangle planes?

Tags: vectors, triangles, plane-geometry

I'm trying to find the intersection points of two triangles using the Tomas Moeller algorithm (https://web.stanford.edu/class/cs277/resources/papers/Moller1997b.pdf)

*the intersection of plane1 and plane2 is a
line, L = O + tD, where D = N1 x N2 is the direction of the line and $O$ is some
point on it.*

https://i.gyazo.com/89e717283d0a8784f9bc2dc3cf1cfebe.png

The paper says the intersection line is equal to $L = O + tD$ but I am unsure how to obtain this point. I have the direction of the line which is the cyan line from one of the vertex positions in the image, but it is not in the correct position. I am assuming this is because I am missing $O$ and it does not say how to calculate it.

The paper does mention that $O$ is not needed towards the end, but I am unsure how to get the correct line position as at the moment, my line direction is correct but is a normalised direction.

How do I calculate $O$ given that all other data is known, i.e. angles, vertices, distances

Edit:

```
    Vector3 D = Vector3.Cross(N2, N1);

    Vector3 a = Vector3.Dot(N2, triangle_wv0) * triangle_wv1;
    Vector3 b = Vector3.Dot(N1, triangle_wv1) * triangle_wv0;
    float c = Vector3.Dot(N2, triangle_wv0);
    float d = Vector3.Dot(N1, triangle_wv1);

    Vector3 O = (a - b) / (c - d);
```

$intersection: (21.8, 18.2, 34.5)$

$N1 = (0.0, 0.0, -1.0)$

$N2 = (0.0, 1.0, 0.0)$

$D = (-1.0, 0.0, 0.0)$

$triangle_wv0 = (21.8, 13.2, 31.0)$

$triangle_wv1 = (21.8, 25.4, 39.7)$

$triangle_wv2 = (36.8, 13.2, 31.0)$

$cutter_wv0 = (8.0, 20.0, 5.0)$

$cutter_wv1 = (8.0, 20.0, 80.0)$

$cutter_wv2 = (83.0, 20.0, 5.0)$

---

**Edit 2**: I think I found the problem and I now have a closer point to the line, but it doesn't seem to work in all cases

At the moment I am only drawing the red line to point $O$ to see if the point is on the intersection line and that does not seem to be correct.

https://i.gyazo.com/7238288c18f38457d13702da6357c691.png - Good, point is on intersection line

https://i.gyazo.com/29b478a873f2af1497f7e513942f2d37.png - Bad, point is not on intersection line

The calculated intersection for the triangles defined above is not correct

$intersection: (21.8, 18.2, 34.5)$

Comment: Keep reading: the first paragraph of section 2.1 concludes that $O$ doesn’t need to be computed.

Comment: @amd yeah I saw, but I'm not sure how to get the correct line position without $O$ as at the moment the line is just a normalised direction.

Comment: If $\mathbf\pi_1$ and $\mathbf\pi_2$ are the homogeneous vectors that represent the planes of the two triangles, then both $O$ and $D$ lie in the null space of $\begin{bmatrix}\mathbf\pi_1&\mathbf\pi_2\end{bmatrix}^T$. $D$ will be the unique point at infinity that is in this null space; for $O$ you can take any finite point. Since this matrix only has two rows, it shouldn’t be hard to come up with a closed-form expression for $O$.

Comment: Sorry I don't follow, my math is not great but I need to understand this for a project I am doing. Could you provide an example?

Comment: Give me the vertices of the triangles in your example and I’ll use them.

Comment: I can see two problems right off the bat: First, if $N_1$ is supposed to be the normal of triangle w’s plane, it’s incorrect. Second, you’re using both normals to compute the intersection point. You should only be using the *other* triangle’s normal.

Comment: @amd Yeah I was experimenting and this combination gave me the closest results so I assumed it was correct, however if I just use N2 (other triangle) the result is $intersection: (21.8, 0.0, 21.5)$ which is off by quite a lot. As for the normal, it's just the normal of the one of the vertices of the triangle as it's facing the -z direction.

Comment: Fortunately, you don’t need $N_1$ for the intersection and since the correct value of $N_1$ also has $0$ for an $x$-component, you get the correct value for $D$, anyway.

Comment: I realised that I forgot to update the value for N1 so that normal was for old values, turned out the one I had was fine. Thank you very much for your examples, it seems to get the correct point now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$O$ can be any point on the line of intersection of the planes. There are various ways to find one, which you can find with an Internet search. Given what you have to work with, though, there’s another direct computation that you can perform that’s not among those in the usual sources.

A general approach to finding a point on the intersection line is to find a line in one of the planes that’s guaranteed to intersect it and then compute the intersection of this second line with the other plane. A reasonably efficient way to do this is to use the Plücker matrix of the line: working in homogeneous coordinates, the line through points $\mathbf p$ and $\mathbf q$ can be represented by the matrix $\mathcal L = \mathbf p\mathbf q^T-\mathbf q\mathbf p^T$. (This is the 3-D analogue of representing a line through two points in 2-D by their cross product.) The intersection of this line with a plane $\mathbf\pi$ is simply $$\mathcal L\mathbf\pi = (\mathbf p\mathbf q^T-\mathbf q\mathbf p^T)\mathbf\pi = (\mathbf q^T\mathbf\pi)\mathbf p-(\mathbf p^T\mathbf\pi)\mathbf q.\tag1$$

In the course of applying Moeller’s algorithm you will have found a pair of triangle vertices $V_i$ and $V_j$ that lie on opposite sides of the intersection line. These are the points $\mathbf p$ and $\mathbf q$ (with a $1$ appended to make them homogeneous, of course). For $\mathbf\pi$ you’ll have the vector $[N^T;d]^T$, i.e., the concatenation of the parameters of the *other* triangle’s plane. Plugging these values into formula (1) gives $$\begin{align} ([V_j;1]\cdot[N;d])[V_i;1] - ([V_i;1]\cdot[N;d])[V_j;1] &= (N\cdot V_j+d)[V_i;1] - (N\cdot V_i+d)[V_j;1] \\
&= [(N\cdot V_j)V_i-(N\cdot V_i)V_j+d(V_i-V_j); N\cdot V_j-N\cdot V_i], \end{align}$$ which in inhomogeneous Cartesian coordinates is $$O = {(N\cdot V_j)V_i-(N\cdot V_i)V_j+d(V_i-V_j) \over N\cdot V_j-N\cdot V_i}.\tag2$$ This method isn’t quite as efficient as a related method that uses a different line and Cramer’s rule, but this way doesn’t require first finding the component of $D$ with the greatest absolute value and then picking out the other coordinates of $N_1$ and $N_2$.

---

*Example:* Using the vertices of the two triangles in the question, we compute $$\mathbf\pi_{tri} = [N_{tri};d_{tri}] = [0. : 0.580607 : -0.814184 : 17.5757] \\ \mathbf\pi_{cut} = [N_{cut};d_{cut}] = [0. : 1. : 0. : -20.],$$ so $$D = N_{tri}\times N_{cut} = (0.814184, 0., 0.)$$ normalized to $(1,0,0)$. Since we’re using the first triangle to compute $O$, we use the values from $\mathbf\pi_{cut}$ in formula (2): $$N\cdot V_j = (0., 1., 0.)\cdot(21.8, 25.4, 39.7) = 25.4 \\ N\cdot V_i = (0., 1., 0.)\cdot(21.8, 13.2, 31.0) = 13.2$$ and finally $$O = {(25.4-20.0)\,(21.8, 13.2, 31.0)-(13.2-20.0)\,(21.8, 25.4, 39.7) \over 25.4-13.2} = (21.8,20.0,35.8492).$$ (I’ve rolled the $d(V_i-V_j)$ term back into the first two terms in this computation.)

Comment: Thanks for the example, I have added the code I am using to get the intersection and I have substituted the values for O, but the results are not correct and it's probably an error on my part. Could you please give it a check over to see what's going wrong? The intersection is $intersection: (25.4, -235929600.0, 32.0)$ for some reason and it seems to be O that is causing the issue. I have tried swapping normals and vertices and managed to get this to a more realistic value but none of them provide any point on the intersection line. I have added values to the OP also. Thanks in advance!

Comment: I found the solution to my previous issue, but now $O$ does not always give a point on the intersection line, I have put 2 images in my OP under **Edit 2**. Would you have any idea why this is?

Comment: @user We’re not here to debug your code. If you provide the vertices of *both* triangles, I can check what you *should* be getting using the formula above.

Comment: Oh of course, I was just seeing if you'd look over the math part where this is calculated. I have removed all the other code and added the second triangle vertices.

Comment: Thanks. You’ve got a couple of errors, but working through an example pointed out an error in my formula: there should also be a $+d(V_i-V_j)$ term in the numerator. Update on the way.

Comment: Thanks again for the help!

Comment: Glad to help. If you’re doing this in a really performance-critical part of your code, check out [this page](http://geomalgorithms.com/a05-_intersect-1.html) for potentially more efficient ways to compute $O$. It also might be possible to modify the algorithm you’re using to also generate one of the intersection points without a lot of extra work, but I’d have to look more closely at it.

Comment: At some point I will need to be looking at optimisations so any information on that would be great help but I can't see it being a major issue until I start to introduce more complex models with potentially hundreds or thousands of triangles. I haven't got there yet but this needs to be running in real-time but providing this isn't a massive performance hit it should be fine.